# counting the number of json array index's

Tags: javascript, json

In my javascript ,i have a json like this,

```
var text = '{"employees":['+
    '{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }' +
']}';
```

i used the below code to to parse my json.
`obj1 = JSON.parse(text);`

what i want to do is to store the json array elements with in a js array(var chartData1=[];). i used the below loop for storing the json array in chartData[]. i was able to successfully store the json array within chartData[] by giving the array condition as i<2.

here is my For loop,

```
for( i=0; i<=2; i++)
{ 
  chartData1.push( [ obj1.employees[i]['firstName'], obj1.employees[i]['lastName'] ])
}
```

what i would like to do is to take of that '2' from the conditional statement with in the for loop and replace it with a variable or expression. i searched in many threads i found that i can use `obj1.employees.length;`(Somthing like this) but this doesnt work in my case . As i am completely a newbie in js i would like to recieve some help from experts. i am sorry for my english.Feel free to point me if i am going  wrong somewhere.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < obj1.employees.length; i++) { ... }` note `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

And take a look at these tutorials: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @webdeb ya that was the mistake i did and i have corrected that. thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj1.employees.length` should be fine as upper bound. I suspect you used the wrong comparison operator ( `<=` instead of `<`). See it working:

```js
var obj1 = { "employees": [
  { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, 
  { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" },
  { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" }
]};

var chartData1 = [];
for( i=0; i < obj1.employees.length; i++)
{ 
  chartData1.push( [ obj1.employees[i]['firstName'], obj1.employees[i]['lastName'] ])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData1));
```

However, there is a better and shorter solution, utilizing the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
var obj1 = { "employees": [
  { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, 
  { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" },
  { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" }
]};

var chartData1 = obj1.employees.map(e => [e.firstName, e.lastName]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also an another solution:

```
var json = JSON.parse(text);
for(var index in json.employees){
    var employee = json.employees[index];
    console.log(employee.firstName, employee.lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After parsing `text`, you will get a JSON object whose only property is `employees`. Essentially, if you do `var parsedContents = JSON.parse(text);`, the value of `parsedContents` is:

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" }, 
        { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" },
        { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" }
    ]
}
```

Consequently, you can get the `employees` array with `JSON.parse(text).employees` and iterate through the array with `Array.prototype.forEach` and friends. Here's the final answer:

```
var employees = JSON.parse(text).employees;

employees.forEach(function (employee) {
    chartData1.push(employee.firstName, employee.lastName);
});
```